# Recommend me a graphing javaScript library

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone point me in the direction of a good jquery / javascript graphing library.  It needs to be able to handle bar and scatter charts.

Specifically i need to be able to capture the click event of a point on the scatter graph so i can load related external data.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) and [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) plugins.

Answer (score 3):

[gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) is a good graphing library to use.

Answer (score 1):

[**D3.JS**](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) is awesome! try it :) some great examples here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Answer (score 0):

**[Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)** is also a good option for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out [CanvasXpress](http://canvasxpress.org/). I've only used it for network representations so far, but it seems quite capable.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [highcharts](http://highcharts.com) . It gives you independence and flexibility.